# R Shiny execute order

Tags: r, shiny

I am fairly new to Shiny (and R for that matter) but I have managed to get an app up and running.

I am however quite confused regarding the "execution order" that takes place when RStudio actually runs the two scripts **server.R** and **ui.R**

To my mind there are 4 sections of code (2 for **server.R** script and 2 for **ui.R** script):

**server.R:**

```
###### SECTION 1

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  ###### SECTION 2


})
```

**ui.R:**

```
###### SECTION 1

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  ###### SECTION 2

)
)
```

**My question is, assuming I have the above correct, which sections are run first, second, third, etc?**

Comment: You can define your global variables in a file named `global.R`.

Comment: Note that what’s relevant for you isn’t compilation order (which, at any rate, is ill-defined in R) but *execution order*.

Comment: Just to expand my comment: content of `server.R` and `ui.R` are parsed and evaluated in different environments and they don't talk to each other (regardless the execution order). You can prove this by defining an object in one of them and see if you can grab it from the other (you can't). Common objects can be defined in a `global.R` file. Objects defined there can be used in both `server.R` and `ui.R`.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph, I will update the question to use "execute" instead of "compile". I still want to know the answer..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `print` statement in each section and run from RStudio.  The message is displayed in your console.  I got

```
[1] "section 1 of UI"
[1] "section 2 of UI"
[1] "section 1 of server"
[1] "section 2 of server"
```

As to the object access, I tried the following and see the variables in each environment.

## ui.R

```
VarDefinedInSec1UI <- 1

print("* section 1 of UI")
cat(ls(), "\n\n")

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  VarDefinedInSec2UI <- 2,

  print("* section 2 of UI"),
  cat(ls(), "\n\n")
))
```

## server.R

```
VarDefinedInSec1Server <- 3

print("* section 1 of server")
cat(ls(), "\n\n")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  VarDefinedInSec2Server <- 4

  print("* section 2 of server")
  cat(ls(), "\n\n")
})
```

I got:

```
[1] "* section 1 of UI"
VarDefinedInSec1UI 

[1] "* section 2 of UI"
VarDefinedInSec1UI VarDefinedInSec2UI 

[1] "* section 1 of server"
VarDefinedInSec1Server 

[1] "* section 2 of server"
input output session VarDefinedInSec2Server
```